# Estimators for $\mu^2$ and $\sigma^2$ for squared normal distribution

Tags: statistics

**Problem.** We have a sample $$(X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n)\,,$$ where $X_1,X_2,\ldots, X_n$ are all i.i.d. with the same distribution as $X=Y^2$, where $Y\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$.

I want to find an estimate of $\mu^2$ and $\sigma^2$, using the method of moments. As a hint, I have been given the relation $$E\left((Y-\mu)^{2k}\right)=(2k-1)!!\cdot \sigma^{2k}\,.$$

**My thoughts.** The first moment centered around the origin is easy to find: $$E(X)=E(Y^2)=V(Y)+(E(Y))^2=\sigma^2+\mu^2\,.$$
Setting this equal to the sample mean gives us one equation, which we can use to find an estimate for $\mu^2$ and $\sigma^2$. But we need one more.

We can now either proceed to compute the second moment around the origin, $E(X^2)=E(Y^4)$ or around the mean $E((X-\mu)^2)=E\left((Y^2-\mu)^2\right)$, but none of these options seem very appealing.

I have, of course, tried to compute $E(Y^4)$ directly, but that leads to an integral where both $y^4$ and $e^{(y-\mu)^2/2\sigma^2}$ are present in the same product, which makes integration by parts hopeless.

I have also tried to find some trick to be able to make use of the hint. But the difference between $(Y^2-\mu)^2$ and $(Y-\mu)^4$ involves terms like $4\mu Y^3$, which are no easier to find the expectancy of than $Y^4$.

And there I've ran out of options. Perhaps someone can give me a little push in a new and more constructive direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note $$\begin{align*} \operatorname{E}[X^2] &= \operatorname{E}[Y^4] \\
&= \operatorname{E}[(Y - \mu + \mu)^4] \\
&= \operatorname{E}[(Y - \mu)^4 + 4\mu (Y - \mu)^3 + 6\mu^2 (Y - \mu)^2 + 4\mu^3 (Y - \mu) + \mu^4] \\
&= \operatorname{E}[(Y - \mu)^4] + 0 + 6\mu^2 \operatorname{E}[(Y - \mu)^2] + 0 + \mu^4, \end{align*}$$
because if $Y$ is normal with mean $\mu$, then $Y - \mu$ is normal with mean $0$, and all odd moments of $Y - \mu$ are zero by symmetry (this is why the hint uses an even exponent; all the odd ones give zero expectation).  Now apply the hint on the remaining portion.